# get Infopath form id after add into Formlibrary

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, form-library

I want try to get Infopath form id after add to form library by following code

```
spFile = fileLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileContents, replaceExistingFiles);
```

and I can't access `spFile.Item.Id` because I added file to form library and I receive this error:

> The object specified does not belong to a list.

Is there any efficient way to get id by name? I tried to get id by file URL but there is no `Item.Id` again.

Comment: I think its case sensitive. Try using `spFile.Item.ID`

Comment: thanks for your replay and of curse its case sensitive and if its wrong error occurs on compile time not run time

Comment: No worries. I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The properties are case sensitive in SharePoint. Normally its `ID`

So try below code

```
spFile.Item.ID
```

This should solve the problem.